# Group output of MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP/MySql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tblDigest";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  echo "<table><tr>
    <th>Diagram</th>
    <th>Headcode</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Dep Time</th>
    <th>Origin</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Arr Time</th>
    <th>Booked Traction</th>
    <th>Actual Traction</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    </tr>";

  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["diagram"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["headcode"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["depDate"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["depTime"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["origin"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["destination"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["arrTime"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["bookedTraction"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["actualTraction"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["type"] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

  }

  echo "</table>";
}
```

I would like to group the results by 'diagram', so that I can display them as an accordion. Is there any easy way to do this?

Failing that, how can I get the value for the first row of the table (so I can have a `$diagNo` variable and compare `$row["diagram"]` against that to find out when it has changed.

Comment: It's bit unclear for me what you're trying to achieve. Could you provide an example?

Comment: `ORDER BY diagram` Then compare previous iteration `diagram` with the current one.

Comment: Order by `diagram` and monitor in the loop with a variable when the value of that column changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your results by `diagram` and watch when its value changes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tblDigest ORDER BY diagram";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  echo "<table><tr>
    <th>Diagram</th>
    <th>Headcode</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Dep Time</th>
    <th>Origin</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Arr Time</th>
    <th>Booked Traction</th>
    <th>Actual Traction</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    </tr>";

  // output data of each row
  $oldDiagram = '';
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if($oldDiagram == '')
    {
      // this is the first diagram - create the first accordeon
      $oldDiagram = $row['diagram'];
    }
    elseif($oldDiagram != $row['diagram'])
    {
      // a new group starts right now - create new accordeon
      $oldDiagram = $row['diagram'];
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["diagram"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["headcode"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["depDate"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["depTime"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["origin"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["destination"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["arrTime"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["bookedTraction"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["actualTraction"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["type"] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

  }

  echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: @ChrisCordner Hello Chris. If this answer answers your question please accept it. [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)